# php segmented file uploads seperated in array

Tags: php, arrays, file, input

I have created an dynamic registration table - and related to one of the segments I need to be able to upload a file.

It all works like dandy. Except the fileupload.

Doing an print_r($_FILES); after attempted upload gives this:

```
    [0]=>
     array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "image001 (3).jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "image001 (2).jpg"
}
["type"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
["tmp_name"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpdqCWSl"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpabqqwj"
}
["error"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
}
["size"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1288)
  [1]=>
  int(1288)
}
```

}
}

Here it kind of merges the two uploads into the same array instead of making the array size of two sub arrays.

```
<td style='display:none;' class=td_register_purchases>
    <input type=text name=registration[][purchase_data] id=purchase_data class=purchase_data>
    <select name='registration[][purchase_type]' id=select_purchase class=purchase_type>
        <option value=1>Accomodation</option>
        <option value=2>Catering</option>
        <option value=3>Tools</option>
        <option value=4>Software/License</option>
        <option value=5>Hardware</option>
    </select>
    <textarea rows=2 cols=50 name='registration[][purchase_comment]' class=purchase_comment placeholder='Comment Area'></textarea>
    <input type=file name='upload_file[]' class='upload-file'> Attachment
</td>
```

I could work with this result:

```
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "image001 (3).jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpdqCWSl"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1288)
    }
  }

  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "image001 (2).jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpabqqwj"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1288)
    }
  }
}
```

But I am probably making a mistake somewhere that could fix it all.

Answer (score 0):

Working hard.. And found a - not beautifull solution ;-)

```
    $number_files = sizeof($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
    $fields = 4;
    $field_count = 0;
    $row_count = 0;
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        for($x = 0; $x < $number_files; $x++) {
            foreach ($_FILES AS $reg_array) {
                foreach ($reg_array AS $segment => $value)
                {
                    if ($field_count == $fields)
                    {
                        $temp_files[$row_count][$segment] = $value[$x];
                        $field_count = 0;
                        $row_count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $field_count++;
                        $temp_files[$row_count][$segment] = $value[$x];
                    }
                } // end foreach
            } // end foreach
        } // end for
    } // end if
```